# How to deserialize from JSON string to Enum using Jackson and CXF

Tags: java, json, enums, cxf, jackson

I am playing @JsonCreator with a static factory in the Enum but CXF doesn't detect and call the updateUser method when the Json object with "Sex":"Male" is present in the request payload. It works when I take out this string representation of the enum.

Any ideas how to structure these three classes/enum to get de-serialization working from String to Enum. Thanks!

UserResource:

```
@PUT
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/{user-id}")
public Response updateUser(UserBean user, @PathParam("user-id") Long userId) {
    user.setId(userId);
    UserBean registeredUser = userService.updateUser(user);
    return Response.ok().entity(registeredUser).build();
}
```

And UserBean:

```
public class UserBean {

private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String password;
private Sex sex;
    .....
```

And the Enum:

```
public enum Sex {

FEMALE("Female", 0),
MALE("Male", 1);

private String desc;
private int value;

Sex(String desc, int value) {
    this.desc = desc;
    this.value = value;
}

public String desc() {
    return desc;
}

@JsonValue
public int value() {
    return value;
}

@JsonCreator
public static Sex fromString(@JsonProperty("sex") String desc) {
    for (Sex type : Sex.values()) {
        if (type.equals(desc)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to match in your `fromString` function? You need to match `type.desc` with the string `desc` passed to the `fromString` fuction. Something like this: `type.desc.equals(desc)`